# Different result in GZIP decompress (PHP / Python)

Tags: python, php, gzip

I'm having a gzipped file that seems to be missing characters when I uncompress the data in PHP. However when I do this for e.g. in Python the characters are present. In this case the last 2 characters (']}') are missing, which makes the data an invalid JSON.

Below 2 examples that both output different results; how is it possible that PHP doesn't output the full data? I've also inspected the GZIP content and it looks like the length and CRC are not valid; at least when I compare the structure with the data from this site: https://docs.fileformat.com/compression/gz/

```
<?php

$base64gzip = 'H4sIAAAAAAAAA7XSO04DQAwE0J5jbE3h8d9cJUoRiSPQcXmEFKR4KFKlfdr12Lv+Pp+3r9v5uFwORnTSACTO9f3tUcKfiLbOsFQsEVMxEkwtMRNROtO9b4V0yT5TAcoq5O5QBtkssSeV6LxnSUXWVEKDp5jmDocmNa3e6ZapYJE9OypCWXxXDo0BC2VJKr+qT3AdTXsialw5BHb/5ZBwbRNHWm2C51/aA3n/IwNX9+RJaveE369mcdrOmNFXScdLxKUg64GgkkqLFrz4JjJ+rj/Cx4XMxgMAAB+LCAAAAAAAAAOLrQUAZzx4YAIAAAA=';

echo gzdecode(base64_decode($base64gzip));
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gzip
import base64

base64gzip = '''H4sIAAAAAAAAA7XSO04DQAwE0J5jbE3h8d9cJUoRiSPQcXmEFKR4KFKlfdr12Lv+Pp+3r9v5uFwORnTSACTO9f3tUcKfiLbOsFQsEVMxEkwtMRNROtO9b4V0yT5TAcoq5O5QBtkssSeV6LxnSUXWVEKDp5jmDocmNa3e6ZapYJE9OypCWXxXDo0BC2VJKr+qT3AdTXsialw5BHb/5ZBwbRNHWm2C51/aA3n/IwNX9+RJaveE369mcdrOmNFXScdLxKUg64GgkkqLFrz4JjJ+rj/Cx4XMxgMAAB+LCAAAAAAAAAOLrQUAZzx4YAIAAAA='''

print(gzip.decompress(base64.b64decode(base64gzip)))
```

^^ Python outputs this data, including the last ']}' characters.

```
b'{"data":[["190296311161"],\n["190296311154"],\n["190296311154"],\n["190296328299"],\n["190296328275"],\n["190296303203"],\n["190296303197"],\n["190296333002"],\n["190296303883"],\n["190296350870"],\n["190296307515"],\n["190296307164"],\n["190296309168"],\n["190296309151"],\n["190296305863"],\n["075679761255"],\n["190296303982"],\n["190296303975"],\n["190296332784"],\n["190296336621"],\n["190296336607"],\n["190296317552"],\n["190296317545"],\n["190296352591"],\n["190296352584"],\n["190296306297"],\n["190296334955"],\n["190296352263"],\n["190296352263"],\n["190296323584"],\n["190296350139"],\n["5054283041637"],\n["5054283014655"],\n["5054283014648"],\n["5054283014631"],\n["190296350146"],\n["190296306273"],\n["190296310751"],\n["190296310744"],\n["190296315992"],\n["190296315992"],\n["190296315992"],\n["190296315992"],\n["190296315992"],\n["190296315985"],\n["190296315985"],\n["190296315985"],\n["190296315985"],\n["190296315985"],\n["190296340710"],\n["5054283120622"],\n["190296305870"],\n["190296330094"]]}'
```

Can some one point me in the right direction why this fails in PHP and how I can still make sure I get the same content as for e.g. in Python?

Comment: you should read comments on PHP page for [gzdecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode). It seems people had also some problems with this function because it truncates string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gzip stream is valid and correct. It consists of two gzip members, each of which is a valid gzip stream on its own, the second of which contains only the the characters `]}`. Python is correctly decoding both gzip members, whereas it appears that PHP is decoding only the first gzip member, ignoring and silently discarding the second.

This is a bug in PHP's `gzdecode()`, and appears to still be there in the latest PHP.

An alternative is to use `inflate_init()`, `inflate_add()`, and `inflate_get_read_len()` in a loop to read all of the members. The key is that `inflate_get_read_len()` is the number of bytes of the gzip stream that have been consumed so far, enabling you to find the start of the next gzip member. Here is an example I ran in a PHP playground with your data to show the idea:

```
$b64 = 'H4sIAAAAAAAAA7XSO04DQAwE0J5jbE3h8d9cJUoRiSPQcXmEFKR4KFKlfdr12Lv+Pp+3r9v5uFwORnTSACTO9f3tUcKfiLbOsFQsEVMxEkwtMRNROtO9b4V0yT5TAcoq5O5QBtkssSeV6LxnSUXWVEKDp5jmDocmNa3e6ZapYJE9OypCWXxXDo0BC2VJKr+qT3AdTXsialw5BHb/5ZBwbRNHWm2C51/aA3n/IwNX9+RJaveE369mcdrOmNFXScdLxKUg64GgkkqLFrz4JjJ+rj/Cx4XMxgMAAB+LCAAAAAAAAAOLrQUAZzx4YAIAAAA=';
$bin = base64_decode($b64);
$gz = inflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_GZIP);
$dec = inflate_add($gz, $bin);
echo inflate_get_status($gz), "\n";
echo inflate_get_read_len($gz), "\n";
echo strlen($dec), "\n";
$used = inflate_get_read_len($gz);
$gz = inflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_GZIP);
$dec .= inflate_add($gz, substr($bin, $used));
echo inflate_get_status($gz), "\n";
echo inflate_get_read_len($gz), "\n";
echo strlen($dec), "\n";
```

This outputs:

```
1
217
966
1
22
968
```

where the `1`'s are the expected return codes for a complete and correct gzip member (make sure to check for that), the `217` and the `22` are the lengths of the two gzip members, and the `966` and `968` are the accumulated amounts of decompressed data, with the second one showing that those errant two characters at the end were added.

You can write your own `gzdecode_complete()` using those functions that does not have the bug.

Comment: Thank you Mark, this really clarifies the issue!